# BeginInvoke clarification

Tags: c#, methods, begininvoke

So I studied that beginInvoke calls a method from another thread. (please correct me if I'm wrong)

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            red_light1 = comport.message(4, 8, 32); 
            if (red_light1 == "1") 
            {
                ellipse1.FillEllipse(red_on, 250, 133, 24, 24);
            }
            else
            { 
                ellipse1.FillEllipse(red_off, 250, 133, 24, 24);
                }));
                Thread.Sleep(300);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BUT I want to read another 5 values in this "action", I don't know how to call it.

How to implement a method that reads 6 variables like in my code and after call it.

```
 method implementation
{

//no parameters & no return value, just read and store the values in variables like "red_light1" and after color some ellipses depending on values (1|0).

}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke( **method call** );
        Thread.Sleep(300);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing has no sense.

You seem to be using a `BackgroundWorker`, which is typically used to perform heavy operations (on the background thread obtained form the ThreadPool), and then you're not doing anything heavy on that background thread

In fact you're not doing anything at all in it:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // a loop that never exits !!!!
    // no break, no cancel, nothing!!!
    while (true) 
    {
        // here is the Background thread
        //... and absolutely NOTHING happens here...

        // the code that follows gets invoked on the UI thread
        // (which defeats the purpose of the BackgroundWorker...)
        // then immediately returns (because it's asynchronous)
        // to be invoked again
        // and again, and again...
        // (Is your app unresponsive perhaps? doesn't it hang?)
        this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            red_light1 = comport.message(4, 8, 32); 
            if (red_light1 == "1") 
            {
                ellipse1.FillEllipse(red_on, 250, 133, 24, 24);
            }
            else
            { 
                ellipse1.FillEllipse(red_off, 250, 133, 24, 24);
                }));

                // Your UI hangs here !!!
                // (Because you're putting your UI thread to sleep!)
                // At least call Thread.Sleep() in the background thread.
                // Or call synchronous Invoke() instead of asynchronous BeginInvoke()
                // so your background thread waits untill the operation on UI thread
                // is completed before trying to perform it again
                Thread.Sleep(300);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. I need continuously reading from arduino that is why I made an infinite while. (maybe is not correct but that is the reason).                                          2. It is not heavy because I only give an example with one variable "red_light1".                       3. Yes, my UI is not very resposive.    4. Exaplain me please how to do this

Comment: this http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/112547-using-the-backgroundworker-in-c%23/ or here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners are good examples of using BackgroundWorker, here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.85).aspx is explained how to use Invoke to update UI. I recommend Invoke instead of BeginInvoke if you want to wait for UI to update

Comment: one more question: are you using SerialPort class to read data? If that's the case, maybe you should consider using DataReceived https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx event instead of a background worker to process your data?